# Parse Markdowns in TextBlock in UWP .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I Want to parse a string which contains markdown and I also want to display the parsed markdown in the `TextBlock` of UWP App.

Some of the markdowns I want to parse :-

1. `__bold__`
2. `_italic_`
3. `~!spoiler!~` - Here the text "spoiler" will be hidden and when I click it, it will show up the text.
4. `youtube("https://youtu.be/aUnak1")` - This will embed a youtube video.
5. `[hyperlink](https://google.com)` - Hyperlink.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this in UWP App. If Someone knows please help me.

Thanks in Advnace...

Comment: That's no different than asking how to parse any other document format. You need a library. There's nothing built-in. There are several Markdown parsers in NuGet. You'd need a RichTextBlock to display the formatting though

Comment: On the other hand, what you posted is *not* MarkDown. It's not RST either. If that's your own custom syntax you'll have to write your own parser and generate the blocks needed by RichTextBlock

Comment: If you actually use Markdown an option is to use the MarkDig package and display the generated HTML in a Web view

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, it's a custom markdown. It is used in Anilist.co website. You have any idea, how to make a custom parser??

Comment: Making a parser can be incredibly difficult.  For example, is there a difference between `__[hyperlink](https://google.com)__` and `[__hyperlink__](https://google.com)`?  You may want to look at using https://commonmark.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the Windows Community Toolkit
it actually features a MarkdownTextBlock:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Markdown/

You can also take a look at the Windows Community Toolkit sample app:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq